# Display different smiley when entering ":)"

Tags: emoji

If you enter `:)` in WordPress, it automatically replaces it with:

[image]

Is there a way to use a different smiley for the `:)`

Comment: Hi krish, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Answer (score 15):

### Overriding the emoji of :) to

The content smilies are converted with:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies' );
```

where [this part](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ae2657dd32a273a5746354629252bb00c5df689f/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2445) of the `convert_smilies()` function is of importance:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback( $wp_smiliessearch, 'translate_smiley', $content );
```

If we peek into `translate_smiley()` then we find the [following](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ae2657dd32a273a5746354629252bb00c5df689f/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2391-L2394):

```
// Don't convert smilies that aren't images - they're probably emoji.
if ( ! in_array( $ext, $image_exts ) ) {
     return $img;
}
```

before the `smilies_src` filter is applied.

So this filter isn't available in the case of the `:)` smiley.

We have the smilies initialized with:

```
add_action( 'init', 'smilies_init', 5 );
```

and within the function description for `smilies_init()` we can read the [following](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ae2657dd32a273a5746354629252bb00c5df689f/wp-includes/functions.php#L3177-L3179):

> Plugins may override the default smiley list by setting the `$wpsmiliestrans`
>   to an array, with the key the code the blogger types in and the value the
>   image file.

Here's the global [`$wpsmiliestrans`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ae2657dd32a273a5746354629252bb00c5df689f/wp-includes/functions.php#L3200) array:

```
$wpsmiliestrans = array(
    ':mrgreen:' => 'mrgreen.png',
    ':neutral:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x90",
    ':twisted:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x88",
    ':arrow:' => "\xe2\x9e\xa1",
    ':shock:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xaf",
    ':smile:' => "\xf0\x9f\x99\x82",
    ':???:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x95",
    ':cool:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x8e",
    ':evil:' => "\xf0\x9f\x91\xbf",
    ':grin:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x80",
    ':idea:' => "\xf0\x9f\x92\xa1",
    ':oops:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xb3",
    ':razz:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x9b",
    ':roll:' => 'rolleyes.png',
    ':wink:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x89",
    ':cry:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xa5",
    ':eek:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xae",
    ':lol:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x86",
    ':mad:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xa1",
    ':sad:' => "\xf0\x9f\x99\x81",
    '8-)' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x8e",
    '8-O' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xaf",
    ':-(' => "\xf0\x9f\x99\x81",
    ':-)' => "\xf0\x9f\x99\x82",
    ':-?' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x95",
    ':-D' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x80",
    ':-P' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x9b",
    ':-o' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xae",
    ':-x' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xa1",
    ':-|' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x90",
    ';-)' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x89",
    // This one transformation breaks regular text with frequency.
    //     '8)' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x8e",
    '8O' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xaf",
    ':(' => "\xf0\x9f\x99\x81",
    ':)' => "\xf0\x9f\x99\x82",
    ':?' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x95",
    ':D' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x80",
    ':P' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x9b",
    ':o' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xae",
    ':x' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xa1",
    ':|' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x90",
    ';)' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x89",
    ':!:' => "\xe2\x9d\x97",
    ':?:' => "\xe2\x9d\x93",
);
```

or the nicer ksorted display:

```
Array
(
    [;-)] => 
    [;)] => 
    [:|] => 
    [:x] => 
    [:wink:] => 
    [:twisted:] => 
    [:smile:] => 
    [:shock:] => 
    [:sad:] => 
    [:roll:] => rolleyes.png
    [:razz:] => 
    [:oops:] => 
    [:o] => 
    [:neutral:] => 
    [:mrgreen:] => mrgreen.png
    [:mad:] => 
    [:lol:] => 
    [:idea:] => 
    [:grin:] => 
    [:evil:] => 
    [:eek:] => 
    [:cry:] => 
    [:cool:] => 
    [:arrow:] => ➡
    [:P] => 
    [:D] => 
    [:???:] => 
    [:?:] => ❓
    [:?] => 
    [:-|] => 
    [:-x] => 
    [:-o] => 
    [:-P] => 
    [:-D] => 
    [:-?] => 
    [:-)] => 
    [:-(] => 
    [:)] => 
    [:(] => 
    [:!:] => ❗
    [8O] => 
    [8-O] => 
    [8-)] => 
)
```

So if I correctly understand the above core comment, then we could do the following:

```
/**
 * :) as the cool emoji
 */
add_action( 'init', function() use ( &$wpsmiliestrans )
{
    if( is_array( $wpsmiliestrans ) && get_option( 'use_smilies' ) )
        $wpsmiliestrans[':)'] = $wpsmiliestrans[':cool:'];

}, 6 );
```

but this only works for predefined smiley keys, for the `$wp_smiliessearch` to work.

*But I don't like this suggested approach, modifying the global array! Hopefully there's another one better!*

### Demo plugin -

I tried to come up with an application for this. I'm not sure if this already exists, but here it is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Santa's Smile In December
 * Description: Change the emoji of :) to the Santa Claus emoji, but only in December
 * Plugin URI:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/218496/26350
 */
add_action( 'init', function() use ( &$wpsmiliestrans )
{
    // :) as Santa Claus
    if( 
           is_array( $wpsmiliestrans ) 
        && get_option( 'use_smilies' ) 
        && 12 == current_time( 'n' ) 
    )
        $wpsmiliestrans[':)'] = "\xF0\x9F\x8E\x85";

}, 6 );
```

Thanks to **Ismael Miguel** for the global [comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218474/display-different-smiley-when-entering/218496#comment319909_218496), I rewrote the snippets accordingly.

Here's the [newly created](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218474/display-different-smiley-when-entering/218496#comment319904_218496) ticket [#35905](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35905) by **Pieter Goosen**, regarding a new `smilies_trans` filter.

### Update - WordPress 4.7+

The new filter will be [available](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35905) in WordPress 4.7+, but it's name will be  `smilies` not `smilies_trans`.

Our above examples can be written as:

```
add_filter( 'smilies', function( $smilies )
{
    if( isset( $smilies[':cool:'] ) )
        $smilies[':)'] = $smilies[':cool:'];

    return $smilies;
} );
```

or explicitly with:

```
add_filter( 'smilies', function( $smilies )
{
    $smilies[':)'] = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x8e";

    return $smilies;
} );
```

The demo plugin becomes:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Santa's Smile In December
 * Description: Change the emoji of :) to the Santa Claus emoji, but only in December
 * Plugin URI:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/218496/26350
 */

add_filter( 'smilies', function( $smilies )
{
    // :) as Santa Claus
    if( get_option( 'use_smilies' ) && 12 == current_time( 'n' ) )
        $smilies[':)'] = "\xF0\x9F\x8E\x85";

    return $smilies;
} );
```

We don't need to mess around with the global `$wpsmiliestrans` array anymore!

Comment: Would the smilies work with every font then?

Comment: Strange how different the smileys look between my tab and pc. :-) Anyways, jip, also don't like modifying around with globals, but this seems like the best you are going to get out of this deal. I think we might look into adding a proper filter in core which we can use to filter smileys instead of altering a crappy global. ;-)

Comment: [trac ticket #35905](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35905) submitted. Lets cross fingers that we get a proper filter

Comment: How about `add_action( 'init', function() use (&$wpsmiliestrans){ $wpsmiliestrans[':)'] = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x8e"; }, 6 );`?

Comment: I've not looked into how the emoji's in general would fail to display rob_st. it will be interesting to follow the ticket @PieterGoosen That's an interesting one-liner Ismael Miguel ;-)

Comment: The goal wasn't for it to be a one-liner, but to show the syntax you can use to eliminate that ugly and God-forbidden `global`. Using the `use(&$var)` syntax, you create a reference to the variable. This means that your `$wpsmiliestrans` will have faster access times, since you access a *local* reference over an *out-of-scope*  global.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment. I like this approach, so let me adjust the above code accordingly, thanks. @IsmaelMiguel

Comment: Thank you so much! The PHP developer in me is really happy for you getting rid of that awful `global`. Please, promise me you will *never* use a `global` (at least, with `lamba` functions) again. Also, notice that some people (a really high number) write `(:` instead of `:)`, which makes it harder for this purpose.

Comment: It's a promise - actually I use the `use` keyword a lot in my answers here, but it's a good reminder regarding the globals, thanks again (:)  <-- maybe we could use a symmetric smiley for better accessability for everyone @IsmaelMiguel

Comment: That is actually a smiley on it's own. It looks like that mask that has a sad and happy face.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [WordPress Codex on using smilies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Smilies):

> Upload the images you want with the same name to your server (say in wp-content/images/smilies) and put this in your theme's function.php:
>
> ```
> add_filter( 'smilies_src', 'my_custom_smilies_src', 10, 3 );
>    function my_custom_smilies_src($img_src, $img, $siteurl){
>        return $siteurl.'/wp-content/images/smilies/'.$img;
>    }
> ```
>
> That will replace http://example.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_question.gif with http://example.com/wp-content/images/smilies/icon_question.gif

Comment: Not sure why the Codex demo is assuming 10 input arguments, instead of 3? But I think this is overriden by the Emoji's.

Comment: I suppose it is meant to be the priority, so the order seems incorrect. I changed it in the Codex, hoping we didn't get it wrong :-)

Comment: I have corrected your edit in the codex and corrected your code in your answer. The allowed arguments should be `3`, setting it to `1` will fail your code as  `$img`, `$siteurl` will be ignored and will therefor be undefined in your filter :-)