# Notice: Undefined property: wpdb::$current_post What can be wrong?

Tags: code

I'm working on a WordPress site and I use the following code to show posts in two columns on archive and category pages:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 0 === ++$GLOBALS['wpdb']->current_post % 2 ? 'grid col-340 fit' : 'grid col-340' ); ?>>
```

With debug set to "true" I got the following notice:

> Notice: Undefined property: wpdb::$current_post in D:\beta\www.beta.dev\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 684

What can be wrong with this code? I noticed that this notice appeared with WordPress version 4+

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are problems with this part:

```
 ++$GLOBALS['wpdb']->current_post
```

There's no `current_post` property of the `wpdb` class, here you're most likely  confusing the `wpdb` class with the `WP_Query` class.

Also we wouldn't want in general to modify the `current_post` property of the global `WP_Query`, it could surely "bite us" if we mess with the globals ;-)

Note that the `current_post` property of `WP_Query` is already doing the counting for us with `$this->current_post++`; inside `next_post()`, that's called within `the_post()`. See [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5a7a3bb9245ca84467d36c7a1a96129c0dbd10af/wp-includes/query.php#L3846). So there's no need to increase it manually (++) within the loop.

Here's an example using the `post_class` filter, with the help of a *static* variable:

```
add_filter( 'post_class', function( $classes ) 
{
    static $instance = 0;

    if( in_the_loop() )
        $classes[] = ( 0 === $instance++ % 2 ) ? 'even' : 'odd';        

    return $classes;
} );
```

where we target post classes in the main query loop. Just remember to modify the even/odd classes and other restrictions to your needs.

Using the `post_class` filter could mean better re-usability for our template parts.

### Update

It looks like you're using the first version of @toscho's one-liner [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44976/26350), creating a custom `current_post` property (for counting) of the global `wpdb` object. He suggested then to use the prefixed custom property, like `wpse_post_counter`. But it looks like it needs an initialization to avoid the PHP notice.

@kaiser did post a great answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44908/26350) that uses the `current_post` property of the global `$wp_query` (probably not the global `$wpdb`).

Since I gave a [promise here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218474/display-different-smiley-when-entering/218496#comment319921_218496), regarding *anonymous* functions and *global* variables, I should rewrite it to: See my [edit here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44908/26350)
- where we use the `use` keyword to pass on the global `$wp_query` object.

Comment: [Here's](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44845/how-to-mark-every-3rd-post) a post where I found the same method that I use. However, I'm a bit confused. What is the corect code in order to avoid that notice? Thanks.

Comment: Knott: Hopefully @toscho can explain the post you linked to, but you could try `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->current_post` instead, I think I would go with the `post_class` filter instead, to keep the template code somewhat cleaner, better re-usability and easier to read.

Comment: Please just use the "Alternative" (a custom object property with your own prefix) if you go down that route.

Comment: @birgire You could simple use `$GLOBALS['wpdb']->current_post % 2` instead of introducing your own counter. If you want to micro-optimize, call `global $wpdb` upfront, so you don't have to reference it from the global array.

Comment: @kaiser does it really work for you from the global `wpdb` object? Not sure why that would work, maybe I'm missing something obvious hehe

Comment: @knott ps: the workaround trial suggestion was  `0 === $GLOBALS['wp_query']->current_post % 2 `, i.e. without modifying any globals with `++` (looks like you're in the main query loop), but I would recommend the `post_class` filter.

Comment: @birgire I actually meant to use `global $wpdb` and `$wp_query->current_post`  inside your `if ( in_the_loop() )` condition. Also, you can assign arbitrary properties to objects like `$GLOBALS['wpdb']->wpse219381_foo` without a problem. Prefixing them should be enough. Also, I don't have a dev setup for WP at the moment, so I am not sure if `current_post` is a property of `wp_query` or `wpdb`. I assume the former has it.

Comment: thanks @kaiser for the clarification: the `current_post` is a property of `WP_Query`, I just thought I was misunderstanding (wouldn't be the first or last time ;-) that it should also be part of part of `wpdb`. Also there was no initialization before ++, so it triggers a PHP notice. Yes I sometimes like to create custom properties of e.g. the `WP_Query` object, to simplify life.

Comment: @kaiser This makes sense to me now as well. Thanks for explaining. birgire: I was just in the dark as you. +another1 for your update. I think that would be really helpful to many other people. Cleverly abusing globals could be a fun new way to explore, although I still do not really buy into this yet, still throwing caution to the wind ;-)

Comment: Here's a [similar answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44908/385).

Comment: yes I already linked to it and upvoted, just let me know if you prefer a short  edit of your answer instead ;-) @kaiser

Comment: @birgire And me wondered about the coincidence of upvote and discussion :) Yes, as always: Please edit for the greater goods.

Answer (score -2):

use `get_the_ID()` to get the current post id

```
<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>
```

and this is how you call Global variable in wp `global $wpdb;`;